# discord.py method call from another function error

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I have this function `async def profile(self, ctx, region, *, summoner)` and I'm trying to call it from another function with `await self.profile(ctx, region, summoner)`, and it gives an error:

```
> Too many positional arguments for method callpylint Missing mandatory
> keyword argument 'summoner' in method callpylint
```

The problem is with the " * " in the profile function. How can I make this work without removing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Bare star (*) is used to force the caller to use named arguments. You can refer to the [doc](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#function-definitions) here for further details.

Update the call as follows,

`await self.profile(ctx, region, summoner=summoner)`